# can keras use sklearn in custom metrics to create micro f1_score

Tags: python, keras

I found a version in stackoverflow

```
from keras import backend as K

def f1(y_true, y_pred):
    def recall(y_true, y_pred):
        """Recall metric.

        Only computes a batch-wise average of recall.

        Computes the recall, a metric for multi-label classification of
        how many relevant items are selected.
        """
        true_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true * y_pred, 0, 1)))
        possible_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true, 0, 1)))
        recall = true_positives / (possible_positives + K.epsilon())
        return recall

    def precision(y_true, y_pred):
        """Precision metric.

        Only computes a batch-wise average of precision.

        Computes the precision, a metric for multi-label classification of
        how many selected items are relevant.
        """
        true_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true * y_pred, 0, 1)))
        predicted_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_pred, 0, 1)))
        precision = true_positives / (predicted_positives + K.epsilon())
        return precision
    precision = precision(y_true, y_pred)
    recall = recall(y_true, y_pred)
    return 2*((precision*recall)/(precision+recall+K.epsilon()))


model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
          optimizer= "adam",
          metrics=[f1])
```

but could I use sklearn f1_score in creating custom metrics?
I want to use the average of f1_score macro and f1_score micro, could anybody help me? thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the code you have showed above during training each batch. Because which is calculating each batch's F1 Score, and you can see the log printed in your terminal.

---

1/13 [=>............................] - ETA: 4s - loss: 0.2646 - f1: 0.2927

2/13 [===>..........................] - ETA: 4s - loss: 0.2664 - f1: 0.1463

...

13/13 [==============================] - 7s 505ms/step - loss: 0.2615 - f1: 0.1008 - val_loss: 0.2887 - val_f1: 0.1464

---

If you use fit method and want to calculate each epoch's F1, you should try to code like below.

```
class Metrics(Callback):
'''
Defined your personal callback
'''
def on_train_begin(self, logs={}):
    self.val_f1s = []
    self.val_recalls = []
    self.val_precisions = []

def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
    #         val_predict = (np.asarray(self.model.predict(self.validation_data[0]))).round()
    val_predict = np.argmax(np.asarray(self.model.predict(self.validation_data[0])), axis=1)
    #         val_targ = self.validation_data[1]
    val_targ = np.argmax(self.validation_data[1], axis=1)
    _val_f1 = f1_score(val_targ, val_predict, average='macro')
    #         _val_recall = recall_score(val_targ, val_predict)
    #         _val_precision = precision_score(val_targ, val_predict)
    self.val_f1s.append(_val_f1)
    #         self.val_recalls.append(_val_recall)
    #         self.val_precisions.append(_val_precision)
    #         print('— val_f1: %f — val_precision: %f — val_recall %f' %(_val_f1, _val_precision, _val_recall))
    print(' — val_f1:', _val_f1)
    return
```

use your callback fit method.

```
metrics = Metrics()

model.fit_generator(generator=generator_train,
                          steps_per_epoch=len(generator_train),
                          validation_data=generator_val,
                          validation_steps=len(generator_val),
                          epochs=epochs,
                          callbacks=[metrics])
```

There're tips to notice:
If you use fit_generator() method to train, you can only use the code you showed. Otherways, if using fit() method, you can try Callback function.

There all!